# change owa password complexity message

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

When changing the password in OWA 2007 i'm getting a generic error "The password does not meet the complexity requirements". Is there a way to actually give the detailed message about what that complexity is?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Windows account password complexity requirements are binary: they're set, or they're not. (Unless you've compiled a custom filter DLL for password requirements.)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx

> Passwords must contain characters from three of the following five
>   categories:
>
> - Uppercase characters of European languages (A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
> - Lowercase characters of European languages (a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
> - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
> - Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/
> - Any Unicode character that is categorized as an alphabetic character but is not uppercase or lowercase. This includes Unicode
>     characters from Asian languages.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I want to change the error message that shows to the users. The error message is generic. Simply in red text it says "The password does not meet the complexity requirements". I want it to tell them what is required like what you posted above.

Comment: You might be able to trawl through the ASPX pages in OWA to find that string and replace it. Keep in mind that such customizations will not always survive your next Exchange update, so you'll have to re-do it (and it might be in a new place after the upgrade.)